# Custom responsive CSS menu using Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have created this menu for my needs. It is responsive, since I'm using bootstrap, and it is custom, because i needed 2 rows for the right side of the menu. What I need is, how can I have toggle-navigation for lower resolutions than 768x1280? This is how the menu is created:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row col-xs-4">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><img src="img/logo.png"></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="row col-xs-8" >
            <div class="row col-xs-12">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#" class="fb"> </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="li"> </a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="row col-xs-12">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" >
                    <li><a href="#" class="active">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" >Projects</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Using media queries to target your needs would do it.

Comment: yes, but how can i do it, because i'm kind of new into this?

Comment: Add your css to the question

Comment: this menu is using only bootstrap classes, the other css has nothing to do with the menu

Comment: I've created a [demo](http://www.bootply.com/S8vxTXJEO7) for you to make things clearer.

Comment: or if you have some other solution, please share it

Comment: ok, i write my example. It's work fine on my pc.

Comment: @user3652674 It'd be nice if you could at [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) yourself. Really they aren't difficult to grasp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that following example is ok for your needes:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu2">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation2</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <li><img src="img/logo.png"></li>
    </div>
    <div class="row col-xs-8 pull-right">
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse pull-right" id="menu1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#" class="fb"> </a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="li"> </a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
    <div class="row col-xs-12 pull-right">
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse pull-right" id="menu2">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="#" class="active">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" >Projects</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add button like this  where headerCol is id of your div which contains elements you want to collapse. I'm sorry for my bad english. I'll give you example:

This is my header navbar:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#headerCol">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index">MYSITE</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse pull-right" id="headerCol"><!-- start nav-collapse -->
      {% block headernav %}
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="index">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about">About us</a></li>
        <li><a href="questions">Questions</a></li>
          <li><a href="contacts">Contacts</a></li>
      </ul>
     {% endblock %}
    </div><!-- end nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, i know this, but i'm using columns, not this kind of menu, i needed two row menu, and with your example i couldn't achieve it

Comment: I give you only example. If you give ids on your column and make two buttons which will display on collapse ... you'are ready. If you want I'll try your example, and i'll write the solution

Comment: yes, please, i need my kind of structure of the menu... thanks